# About downloading viewable SVF files and derived files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I aim to visualize BIM data using Forge API. For visualization, we are considering offline viewing by running Viewer-related javascript etc locally, but there is a problem.
I do not know how to download SVF files that can be referenced in the viewer with the Model Derivative API. Are all the files included in json obtained by "GET / manifest /"? What is the SDB it contains?

Comment: There are two ways you can extract an SFV file from your model so you can then visualize it inside the forge viewer: 1- using an extension of VS Code called "Autodesk Forge Tools", which allows you to establish a connection with APS using your credentials, upload your object then translate it to SVF, and download the SVF folder to your machine. 2- is using this node js repo: https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io , which takes the URN of your model which you get after uploading it to an APS bucket in the model manifest

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific endpoint, but you can implement it like:

- [Nodejs](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs)
- [C#](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-c-net)
- [PHP](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/php-sample-extract-svf)

Comment: Is there any example how I can consume this extracted svf and data to view it offline?

Comment: @KushagraKasbi for extracting the SVF please refer to my comment above, as for referencing the SVF file, you can add the path of the file in the options of the viewer under the "document" property